# Wrong configuration of naked domain on heroku and godaddy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I try to set a naked domain for my website, I mean like:
if my domain is: www.example.com so i want be able to enter example.com and it will take me to my website too...
I tried to configure it alone but now every time I type example.com
it takes me to www.example.com/www.example.com and of course I get 404.
Please guide me to configure it correctly.
My app is hosted on Heroku and my domain is on Godaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter I solved it , just did typing mistake on the forwarding.